# Multiple directives [myPopup, myDraggable] asking for new/isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive for dialogs (myPopup) and another one for dragging this dialog (myDraggable), but I allways get the error:

> Multiple directives [myPopup, myDraggable] asking for new/isolated scope

Here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kMQ0hK5RnVw5xOBdDq5P?p=preview

What can I do?

JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function myController($scope) {
    $scope.isDraggable = true;
}


app.directive('myPopup', [
    function () {
        "use strict";

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div my-draggable="draggable"class="dialog"><div class="title">{{title}}</div><div class="content" ng-transclude></div></div>',
            scope: {
                title: '@?dialogTitle',
                draggable: '@?isDraggable',
                width: '@?width',
                height: '@?height',
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                // Some code
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                if (scope.width) {
                    element.css('width', scope.width);
                }

                if (scope.height) {
                    element.css('height', scope.height);
                }                    
            }
        };
    }
]);

app.directive('myDraggable', ['$document',
    function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: { enabled: '=myDraggable' },

        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            var startX, startY, initialMouseX, initialMouseY;

            if (scope.enabled === true) {
                elm.bind('mousedown', function ($event) {
                    startX = elm.prop('offsetLeft');
                    startY = elm.prop('offsetTop');
                    initialMouseX = $event.clientX;
                    initialMouseY = $event.clientY;
                    $document.bind('mousemove', mousemove);
                    $document.bind('mouseup', mouseup);
                    $event.preventDefault();
                });
            }

            function getMaxPos() {
                var computetStyle = getComputedStyle(elm[0], null);
                var tx, ty;
                var transformOrigin =
                    computetStyle.transformOrigin ||
                    computetStyle.webkitTransformOrigin ||
                    computetStyle.MozTransformOrigin ||
                    computetStyle.msTransformOrigin ||
                    computetStyle.OTransformOrigin;
                tx = Math.ceil(parseFloat(transformOrigin));
                ty = Math.ceil(parseFloat(transformOrigin.split(" ")[1]));
                return {
                    max: {
                        x: tx + window.innerWidth - elm.prop('offsetWidth'),
                        y: ty + window.innerHeight - elm.prop('offsetHeight')
                    },
                    min: {
                        x: tx,
                        y: ty
                    }
                };
            }

            function mousemove($event) {
                var x = startX + $event.clientX - initialMouseX;
                var y = startY + $event.clientY - initialMouseY;
                var limit = getMaxPos();
                x = (x < limit.max.x) ? ((x > limit.min.x) ? x : limit.min.x) : limit.max.x;
                y = (y < limit.max.y) ? ((y > limit.min.y) ? y : limit.min.y) : limit.max.y;
                elm.css({
                    top: y + 'px',
                    left: x + 'px'
                });
                $event.preventDefault();
            }

            function mouseup() {
                $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I saw, that similar problem occurs when I accidently include my directives js file twice... so maybe it's helpful note for someone....

Comment: Happened to me when I was moving a partial to a directive and forgot to remove the **ng-controller** from the template

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=myPopup&p1=myDraggable&p2=new/isolated%20scope&p3=%3Cdiv%20my-draggable=%22draggable%22%20class=%22dialog%22%20dialog-title=%22My%20Title%22%20is-draggable=%22%7B%7Btrue%7D%7D%22%3E):

> Example scenarios of multiple incompatible directives applied to the
> same element include:
>
> **Multiple directives requesting isolated scope**.
>
> Multiple directives publishing a controller under the same name.
>
> Multiple directives declared with the transclusion option.
>
> Multiple directives attempting to define a template or templateURL.

Try removing isolate scope on `myDraggable`'s directive:

```
app.directive('myDraggable', ['$document',
    function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: { enabled: '=myDraggable' }, //remove this line
```

Replace `scope.enabled` with `attrs.enabled`:

```
if (attrs.enabled == "true") {
```

And modify your template to bind the enable attribute:

```
<div my-draggable="draggable" enabled="{{draggable}}"
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FY1NGGiDCNudRRXZBiKe?p=catalogue)

Comment: Sorry, the DEMO doen´t work, becouse attrs.enabled is in the link-part and so it never will be updated. @Khanh TO

Comment: @Martin: I don't see you bind it anywhere. In case you need to get notified when attrs.enabled is updated, you could try `scope.$watch(function(){ return attrs.enabled },function (value){});`

Answer (score 24):

A DOM element is creating a collision with your attempted isolate scopes. Therefore, you should always ask yourself if an isolate scope is needed.

Consider removing the isolate scope on `myDraggable`, interpolating the myDraggable value (like you did with isDraggable), and accessing the attribute in the `link` function.

```
<div class="draggable" my-draggable="{{isDraggable}}">I am draggable {{isDraggable}}</div>
```

```js
...

replace: false,

link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
  var startX, startY, initialMouseX, initialMouseY,
      enabled = attrs.myDraggable === 'true';
  if (enabled === true) {

...
```

See your updated Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JNLNzm?p=preview) and notice the change in the myPopup template.

If you want to see the myDraggable attribute changes then implement something like:

```js
attrs.$observe('myDraggable', function(iVal) {
  enabled = iVal === 'true';
  // AND/OR
  if (iVal === 'true') doSomething();
});
```

See [Angular Attribute Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) $observe function

Comment: Okay, now I have solved it. Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YCJJ2aBeodoWuKWMOmGH?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome, @Martin! If this is solved will you mark an accepted answer and vote for the relevant answers? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

my error was similar:

*Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [groups, groups] asking for new/isolated scope on:*

In my case I had duplicate declaration of

```
 .component('groups', new GroupsComponent());
```

in app.js/app.ts file

and at the same time on the component itself

```
const groups = angular.module('groups', ['toaster'])
.component('groups', new GroupsComponent());
```

Removing it from app.js/app.ts fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

**There is a way to work around it.**

You will not isolate scope of the directive, instead of it, we will create a new isolated scope using [$new method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new) . This method creates a new child scope, if you use true at 1st parameter it will create an isolated scope:

> If true, then the scope does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope. The scope is isolated, as it can not see parent >scope properties. When creating widgets, it is useful for the widget to not accidentally read parent state.

But it isn't a problem because we have access to private scope by the directive link function, so is possible to work parallel with "parent" and isolated scope into a very close behavior of a directive with an isolated scope.

Se the example bellow:

```
app.directive('myDraggable', ['$document',
    function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: false,
        //scope: { enabled: '=myDraggable', oneWayAttr: "@" }, //Just for reference I introduced a new 
        link: function(parentScope, elem, attr) {
        var scope = parentScope.$new(true); //Simulated isolation.
            scope.oneWayAttr = attr.oneWayAttr; //one-way binding @
            scope.myDraggable = parentScope.$parent.$eval(attr.myDraggable);

            scope.watchmyDraggable = function () {
                    return scope.myDraggable = parentScope.$parent.$eval(attr.myDraggable); //parent -> isolatedscope
            };          
            scope.$watch(scope.watchmyDraggable, function(newValue, oldValue) {
             //(...)
            });

            parentScope.innerScope = scope; //If you need view access, you must create a kind of symbolic link to it.

        //(...)
        }
```

I developed this work around to a validation directive, that's works very well.

Comment: anyway we can have a two-way data binding with this?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it's emulated with an $watch

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar situation. If it doesn't mess up your layout and you definitely need to have an isolate scope on both directives, my suggestion would be to remove the property `replace: true` from the myPopup directive definition.

Answer (score 2):

I have included my directive js file twice when I compressed my app. This caused the error.

Comment: After reading https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2747-accidentally-defining-a-directive-twice-in-angularjs.htm I scrolled down to find out you answered it already. This needs an upvote since the rest is just a distraction when by accident you defined the component twice by mistake. Like this for example: `angular.module('myapp', []).component('thing', Thing).component('thing', Thing)`. The mistake will cause this error once rendered: > Multiple directives [thing, thing] asking for new/isolated scope on: <thing>

Answer (score -1):

Leave out scope: { enabled: '=myDraggable' } from your "myDraggable"-directive you don't need it. So:

```
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work because of this part `if (scope.enabled === true) {
                elm.bind('mousedown', function ($event) {` @Matthias