# How to avoid "Multiple directives" error when using third-party libraries

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Is there any way to use both [angular-table-resize](https://github.com/Tympanix/angular-table-resize) and [AngularJS Tablesort](https://github.com/mattiash/angular-tablesort) for the same table?

If I just do the following:

```
<table resizeable mode="resizeMode" class="table table-striped table-bordered" border="1" ts-wrapper id="myTable">
</table>
```

it gives me the following error:

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [resizeable, tsWrapper]
>   asking for new/isolated scope on:

Is there anything that I can do to avoid this error? How can I use both sorting and resizing on the same table then?

Comment: Can you show us your JS constructor of the `tableSort` ? This is related somewhat : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303368/multiple-directives-mypopup-mydraggable-asking-for-new-isolated-scope but you will require to pass in a reference to the `tableSort` IIRC

Comment: @Pogrindis What do you mean? I don't use a `tableSort` constructor directly in my code. I just add `tableSort` and `ngTableResize` modules to the dependencies array