# How to configure directive that comes from a third-party library

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to configure `directive` that comes from a third-party library?

I'm using a library called [angular-tablesort](https://github.com/mattiash/angular-tablesort) and I want to disable the `scope: true` option that it sets in its `directive`:

```
tableSortModule.directive('tsWrapper', ['$parse', '$compile', function( $parse, $compile ) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        controller: ['$scope', 'tableSortConfig', function($scope, tableSortConfig ) { /* ... */ }
    }
}]);
```

Is there any way to do it w/o modifying the source code of this library?

Comment: what changes are reflected when you change the library itself?

Comment: @Ameer Hamza I need to remove the `scope: true` option because of this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635771/how-to-avoid-multiple-directives-error-when-using-third-party-libraries