# smart table angularjs error multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have the following HTML:

```
    <table st-table="collectionPhoto" st-pipe="getPhotosList" class="pure-table pure-table-striped pure-table-hover pure-table-bordered table-camera">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in photoList| dateFilter:from:to" ng-mobile-click="open(row)">
                <td>{{ ((current_page - 1) * page_size) + $index + 1}}</td>
                <td><img ng-src="{{row.photo}}" class='portrait'></td>
                <td>{{ row.dt}}</td>
                <td>{{ row.views.place.name}}</td>
                <td>{{ row.views.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="pagination-center" st-page-change="rembemberCurrentPage(newPage)" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

And controller JS :

```
.controller('admin.photos.controller', function ($scope, $state, $loader, $fetch, $rootScope, $paginate, $location)
        {
            $scope.photoList = [];
            $loader.show();
            $scope.getPhotosList = function (table) {
                table.pagination.number = 20;
                $paginate.getList(table).then(function (response)
                {
                    $scope.photoList = response.data.data;
//                    $scope.photoList = angular.copy($scope.photoList);
                    $scope.collectionPhoto = response.data.data;
                    $scope.page_size = response.data.per_page;
                    $scope.current_page = response.data.current_page;
                    $scope.rembemberCurrentPage = function (p) {
                        $scope.current_page = p;
                        window.location.hash = window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    };
                    table.pagination.numberOfPages = response.data.last_page;
                    table.pagination.totalItemCount = response.data.total;
                }).finally(function () {
//                    $loader.hide();
                });
            };
```

My problem is that I get the following error : 
Multiple directives [stTable, stTable] asking for new/isolated scope.

Someone knows why such a mistake appears?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303368/multiple-directives-mypopup-mydraggable-asking-for-new-isolated-scope

Comment: This is not helpful for me