# AngularJS - ui-bootstrap accordion - using ng-controller inside ng-repeat doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to construct an accordion list that shows more details when the accordion expands. Here is a simplified version of the template:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <accordion>
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="r in main.results" ng-controller="DetailsController as d">
            <accordion-heading ng-click="d.getDetails(r.id)">
                {{r.name}}
            </accordion-heading>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="v in d.details">{{v.detail}}</li>
            </ul>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</body>
```

The DetailsController initially has an empty details array, but when the function getDetails() is called, that array is populated by a service (detailsService is simply an abstracted $resource call). This part works when not being applied to an accordion, but in this specific situation, nothing happens with the accordion heading is clicked. See below:

```
app.controller('DetailsController', function(detailsService) {
    var vm = this

    var details = []
    var detailsPopulated = false

    var getDetails = function(id) {
        console.log('getDetails()')
        if (!vm.detailsPopulated) {
            console.log('Getting details')
            detailsService.get({id: id}, function(data) {
                vm.details = data.results
                vm.detailsPopulated = true
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        details: details,
        getDetails: getDetails
    }

});
```

This controller works in other cases, but for some reason, the ng-click on the accordion header does not invoke the getDetails function at all - if it did, I would see "getDetails()" in the console, since that is the first statement of the getDetails function.

Even simpler: setting up a controller with mock "details" doesn't work.

```
app.controller('DetailsController', function() {
    var details = [{detail: 'Test'}]

    return {
        details: details
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <accordion>
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="r in main.results" ng-controller="DetailsController as d">
            <accordion-heading>
                {{r.name}}
            </accordion-heading>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="v in d.details">{{v.detail}}</li>
            </ul>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</body>
```

Not even this simplified example with the service and ng-click removed works.

Can anyone advise a solution? I am also trying to accomplish this using the "controller as" technique instead of using $scope everywhere.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunker of this ? Code looks OK. Any errors in console ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not bind `ng-click` to `<accordion-heading>` beacause `ui.bootstrap` will use different `DOM` for `heading`. You can take a look at `developer console` to see what `ui.bootstrap` translate `<accordion-heading>` into `DOM`.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a href="" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading"><span class="ng-scope ng-binding">Header 1</span></a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I think you want to dynamically load the content of `accordion`. One way to achieve this is to `$watch` when the `accordion` is **opened** and perform loading. I have created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/v03k86rx/) to demonstrate the idea. Something you must notice :

1. You can not put `ng-controller` inside `accordion-group` because it will raise **error** `multiple directive asking for isolated scope`. This is beacause `<accordion-group>` is an **isolated** scope and angular will not allow **two scope** : one from **controller scope** and one from directive **isolated scope** to bind into the same **html**. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609770/nested-e-directives-multiple-directives-asking-for-new-isolated-scope). One way to work around it is to put a `div` with `ng-controller` and `ng-repeat` outside `accordion-group`

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="r in main.results" ng-controller="DetailsController as d">
       <accordion-group>
          ...
       </accordion-group>
   </div>
   ```
2. You can add `attrs` **is-open** to `accordion-group` and `$watch` for its change and perform **loading**. `Accordion` directive will change `is-open` value when you `open` or `close` the `accordion`.

Hope it helps.